# Mixin similar to bleed but without transparency

Tags: html, css, sass, susy-compass

How can I get effect like this one marked on picture in SASS with Susy Compass?

[image]

I've tried using bleed mixin but border is on top. Is there a mixin with similar functionality and z-index? Menu is set to float left and content to float right. If there isn't one, how can I obtain this effect?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is z-index (not transparency), and you can take care of that yourself, without any special mixin. Just add your own `z-index` value *in addition to* the `bleed` mixin. (z-index also requires positioning other-than `static`):

```
.item {
  @include bleed(...);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20; // adjust as needed...
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answer. I've was using z-index, but I didn't set position like You did. That was a source of a problem:)